# LOVE2d is giving me an error for a nil value, though it was working fine before I added images to my sprites

Tags: image, lua, sprite, game-development, love2d

I'm working on a top-down zombie survival game, and I had everything for the prototype working, but the moment I add images, everything breaks and I get this error:

```
Error

main.lua:46: attempt to index global 'zombie' (a nil value)


Traceback

[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'
main.lua:46: in function 'load'
[love "callbacks.lua"]:136: in function <[love "callbacks.lua"]:135>
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

now I'm fairly new to the LOVE2d framework so I have no idea what to do, obsoletely any help would be amazing.

my code is:

```
-- Constants
local WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
local WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600

local PLAYER_SPEED = 200
local BULLET_SPEED = 500
local SHOOT_DELAY = 0.2

local MAX_ZOMBIES_PER_WAVE = 10
local WAVE_DELAY = 10

-- Player object
local player = {
  x = WINDOW_WIDTH / 2,
  y = WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2,
  width = 30,
  height = 30,
  angle = 0,
  canShoot = true,
  shootTimer = SHOOT_DELAY,
  health = 3,
  image = nil
}

-- Bullet table
local bullets = {}

-- Zombie table
local zombies = {}
local zombiesRemaining = 0
local waveTimer = 0
local currentWave = 0

-- Game state
local gameState = 'menu'

-- Game over variables
local gameOverTimer = 0
local GAME_OVER_DELAY = 2

function love.load()
  love.window.setMode(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
  love.window.setTitle('Zombie Shooter')

  player.image = love.graphics.newImage('assets/player.png')
  zombie.image = love.graphics.newImage('assets/zombie.png')
end

function love.update(dt)
  if gameState == 'playing' then
    UpdatePlaying(dt)
  elseif gameState == 'gameover' then
    UpdateGameOver(dt)
  end
end

function love.draw()
  if gameState == 'menu' then
    DrawMenu()
  elseif gameState == 'playing' then
    DrawPlaying()
  elseif gameState == 'gameover' then
    DrawGameOver()
  end
end

function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
  if gameState == 'menu' then
    local buttonWidth = 200
    local buttonHeight = 50
    local buttonX = WINDOW_WIDTH / 2 - buttonWidth / 2
    local buttonY = WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2 + 50
    
    if button == 1 and x >= buttonX and x <= buttonX + buttonWidth and
       y >= buttonY and y <= buttonY + buttonHeight then
      StartGame()
    end
  end
end

function UpdatePlaying(dt)
  -- Player movement
  local dx = 0
  local dy = 0
  
  if love.keyboard.isDown('w') then
    dy = -1
  elseif love.keyboard.isDown('s') then
    dy = 1
  end
  
  if love.keyboard.isDown('a') then
    dx = -1
  elseif love.keyboard.isDown('d') then
    dx = 1
  end
  
  local magnitude = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
  if magnitude > 0 then
    dx = dx / magnitude
    dy = dy / magnitude
  end
  
  player.x = player.x + dx * PLAYER_SPEED * dt
  player.y = player.y + dy * PLAYER_SPEED * dt
  
  -- Player rotation
  local mouseX, mouseY = love.mouse.getPosition()
  player.angle = math.atan2(mouseY - player.y, mouseX - player.x)
  
  -- Shooting
  player.shootTimer = player.shootTimer - dt
  if player.shootTimer <= 0 then
    player.canShoot = true
  end
  
  if love.mouse.isDown(1) and player.canShoot then
    local mouseX, mouseY = love.mouse.getPosition()
    ShootBullet(mouseX, mouseY)
  end
  
  -- Bullet movement
  for i = #bullets, 1, -1 do
    local bullet = bullets[i]
    bullet.x = bullet.x + math.cos(bullet.angle) * bullet.speed * dt
    bullet.y = bullet.y + math.sin(bullet.angle) * bullet.speed * dt
    
    if bullet.x < 0 or bullet.x > WINDOW_WIDTH or bullet.y < 0 or bullet.y > WINDOW_HEIGHT then
      table.remove(bullets, i)
    end
  end
  
  -- Zombie movement
  for i = 1, #zombies do
    local zombie = zombies[i]
    local dx = player.x - zombie.x
    local dy = player.y - zombie.y
    local magnitude = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    if magnitude > 0 then
      dx = dx / magnitude
      dy = dy / magnitude
    end
    
    -- Avoid other zombies
    for j = 1, #zombies do
      if i ~= j then
        local otherZombie = zombies[j]
        local avoidDx = zombie.x - otherZombie.x
        local avoidDy = zombie.y - otherZombie.y
        local avoidMagnitude = math.sqrt(avoidDx * avoidDx + avoidDy * avoidDy)
        
        if avoidMagnitude > 0 then
          dx = dx + avoidDx / avoidMagnitude
          dy = dy + avoidDy / avoidMagnitude
        end
      end
    end
    
    magnitude = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    if magnitude > 0 then
      dx = dx / magnitude
      dy = dy / magnitude
    end
    
    zombie.x = zombie.x + dx * zombie.speed * dt
    zombie.y = zombie.y + dy * zombie.speed * dt
  end
  
  -- Collision detection
  for i = #zombies, 1, -1 do
    local zombie = zombies[i]
    
    if CheckCollision(player, zombie) then
      player.health = player.health - 1
      
      if player.health <= 0 then
        EndGame()
      end
      
      table.remove(zombies, i)
    end
    
    for j = #bullets, 1, -1 do
      local bullet = bullets[j]
      
      if CheckCollision(bullet, zombie) then
        table.remove(bullets, j)
        table.remove(zombies, i)
        
        zombiesRemaining = zombiesRemaining - 1
        
        if zombiesRemaining <= 0 then
          StartNextWave()
        end
        
        break
      end
    end
  end
  
  -- Wave timer
  if zombiesRemaining > 0 then
    waveTimer = waveTimer - dt
    if waveTimer <= 0 then
      StartNextWave()
    end
  end
end

function UpdateGameOver(dt)
  gameOverTimer = gameOverTimer + dt
  
  if gameOverTimer >= GAME_OVER_DELAY then
    gameState = 'menu'
  end
end

function DrawMenu()
  love.graphics.clear(0, 0, 0)
  
  love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255)
  love.graphics.setFont(love.graphics.newFont(32))
  love.graphics.printf('Zombie Shooter', 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2 - 50, WINDOW_WIDTH, 'center')
  
  local buttonWidth = 200
  local buttonHeight = 50
  local buttonX = WINDOW_WIDTH / 2 - buttonWidth / 2
  local buttonY = WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2 + 50
  
  love.graphics.setColor(0, 0, 0)
  love.graphics.rectangle('fill', buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)
  
  love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255)
  love.graphics.setFont(love.graphics.newFont(24))
  love.graphics.printf('Start', buttonX, buttonY + buttonHeight / 2 - 12, buttonWidth, 'center')
end

function DrawPlaying()
  love.graphics.clear(0, 0, 0)
  
  -- Draw player
  love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255)
  love.graphics.draw(player.image, player.x, player.y, player.angle, 1, 1, player.width / 2, player.height / 2)
  
  -- Draw bullets
  love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0)
  for i = 1, #bullets do
    local bullet = bullets[i]
    love.graphics.circle('fill', bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.width / 2)
  end
  
  -- Draw zombies
  love.graphics.setColor(0, 255, 0)
  for i = 1, #zombies do
    local zombie = zombies[i]
    love.graphics.draw(zombie.image, zombie.x, zombie.y, 0, 1, 1, zombie.width / 2, zombie.height / 2)
  end
  
  -- Draw health
  love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0)
  love.graphics.setFont(love.graphics.newFont(16))
  love.graphics.print('Health: ' .. player.health, 10, 10)
end

function DrawGameOver()
  love.graphics.clear(0, 0, 0)
  
  love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255)
  love.graphics.setFont(love.graphics.newFont(32))
  love.graphics.printf('Game Over', 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2 - 50, WINDOW_WIDTH, 'center')
end

function StartGame()
  gameState = 'playing'
  
  player.x = WINDOW_WIDTH / 2
  player.y = WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2
  player.angle = 0
  player.canShoot = true
  player.shootTimer = SHOOT_DELAY
  player.health = 3
  
  bullets = {}
  zombies = {}
  zombiesRemaining = 0
  waveTimer = 0
  currentWave = 0
  
  StartNextWave()
end

function EndGame()
  gameState = 'gameover'
  gameOverTimer = 0
end

function StartNextWave()
  currentWave = currentWave + 1
  zombiesRemaining = math.random(1, MAX_ZOMBIES_PER_WAVE * currentWave)
  waveTimer = WAVE_DELAY
  
  for i = 1, zombiesRemaining do
    SpawnZombie()
  end
end

function SpawnZombie()
  local zombie = {
    x = math.random(0, WINDOW_WIDTH),
    y = math.random(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT),
    width = 30,
    height = 30,
    speed = 100,
    image = zombie.image
  }
  
  table.insert(zombies, zombie)
end

function ShootBullet(targetX, targetY)
  local angle = math.atan2(targetY - player.y, targetX - player.x)
  
  local bullet = {
    x = player.x,
    y = player.y,
    width = 5,
    height = 5,
    angle = angle,
    speed = BULLET_SPEED
  }
  
  table.insert(bullets, bullet)
  
  player.canShoot = false
  player.shootTimer = SHOOT_DELAY
end

function CheckCollision(obj1, obj2)
  return obj1.x - obj1.width / 2 < obj2.x + obj2.width / 2 and
         obj1.x + obj1.width / 2 > obj2.x - obj2.width / 2 and
         obj1.y - obj1.height / 2 < obj2.y + obj2.height / 2 and
         obj1.y + obj1.height / 2 > obj2.y - obj2.height / 2
end
```

I've tried removing the image from its function, putting it in different files, and searching up some fixes on the internet, but nothing worked. I was expecting my player and zombie images to load correctly on my sprites.

Answer (score 2):

> main.lua:46: attempt to index global 'zombie' (a nil value)

Line 46 is

```lua
zombie.image = love.graphics.newImage('assets/zombie.png')
```

within the `love.load` function.

At this point in the program, there is no `zombie` variable in scope. There is however the file scope variable

```lua
local zombies = {}
```

Perhaps you meant:

```lua
zombies.image = love.graphics.newImage('assets/zombie.png')
```

But this will not persist, as `zombies` is overwritten with a new table every time `StartGame` is called.

You'll need to find somewhere else to store this image.

This probably happened due to auto-completion, or just auto-*piloting* based on the previous line

```lua
player.image = love.graphics.newImage('assets/player.png')
```

which is valid.

---

As a point of design, you could consider using a table (named `resources` or `assets`, etc.) to store shared sprites in, instead of tacking on to the `zombies` table (and then also having an `image` field for individual zombies).

```lua
local resources = {
    sprites = {},
    sounds = {}
}

function love.load()
    --- ...
    resources.sprites.ZOMBIE = love.graphics.newImage('assets/zombie.png')
    --- ...
end

function DrawPlaying()
    --- ...
    -- Draw zombies
    love.graphics.setColor(0, 255, 0)
    for i = 1, #zombies do
        local zombie = zombies[i]
        love.graphics.draw(resources.sprites.ZOMBIE, zombie.x, zombie.y, 0, 1, 1,
            zombie.width / 2, zombie.height / 2)
    end
    --- ...
end
```

This is obviously personal preference, though.

With some adjustments like the ones shown above (and some thrown together sprites) your game works fairly well. Zombies do tend to wander off-screen though!